# can't understand why code is giving error: TypeError: 0 is read-only

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning JavaScript and was attempting bonfire questions in freecodecamp. My code is meant to make the first letter of each word capital.
Code:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase ();
  var arr = str.split(' ');

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    arr[i][0] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase();           
  }

   str = arr.join (' ');
   return str;
  //return arr[0][0];
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Instead its returning an error: 
TypeError: 0 is read-only

I would have understood the error had I been trying the operation on a string (them being immutable). But I am trying to edit an array which is perfectly mutable.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug, event if it's not returning what you want

Comment: Is there a way to fix my code?

Comment: @Gwendal I am running the code on freecodecamp compiler so maybe thats why you aren't getting the same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not giving any error, but it is not making the first character uppercase either

replace this line

```
arr[i][0] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase();
```

by

```
arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is my code not working because the array is still holding a string or is there some other reason

Comment: @demonSlayer I am not sure exactly why your code is not working since I am not aware of freecodecamp compiler. Their documentation also has no mention of array immutability https://github.com/freecodecamp/freecodecamp/wiki/js-immutable

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is indeed an array. Its elements are mutable, so you can replace `arr[i]` with another string.

However, `arr[i]` is a string. Trying to assign to `arr[i][0]` is not valid because you're trying to modify an immutable string.

The error comes from freeCodeCamp's console, which correctly flags this as illegal, but doesn't give the correct explanation.

Comment: I appreciate this is now 5 years old, but I actually came here from freeCodeCamp with almost the exact same problem and initial misunderstanding and found the answers not entirely helpful. Others have already answered what should be used instead, but not what actually causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You change Your Javascript 
like this

```
function titleCase(str) {
str = str.toLowerCase ();
var arr = str.split(' ');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
 arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);   
}


str = arr.join (' ');
 return str;
//return arr[0][0];
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: I think charat() will be necessary otherwise the whole word will be capitalized